# Merging various different cells

Tags: excel, vba, merge, cell

i need to merge different no. of cells like the one shown with a tick mark at top of the image (refer below attached image link)

i have hundreds of excel files with each one having thousands of rows data in it , can anyone help in generating vba code for this problem?

[image]

tried this but this merged the cells which were only empty , expected was to merge data as shown in the image with empty cells

```
Sub MergeColumnCells()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    'Specify the column you want to merge
    Dim col As Integer
    col = 1 'Change this to the column number you want to merge

    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lastRow
        If Cells(i, col).Value = Cells(i - 1, col).Value Then
            Range(Cells(i - 1, col), Cells(i, col)).Merge
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub MergeColumnCells()
   Dim n As Long, i As Long, lastrow As Long
   n = 1
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   With ActiveSheet
       lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
       For i = 2 To lastrow
          If .Cells(i, "A") = "" Then
              n = n + 1
          ElseIf n > 1 Then
              .Cells(i - n, "A").Resize(n).Merge
              n = 1
          End If
       Next
       ' last group
       If n > 1 Then
           .Cells(i - n, "A").Resize(n).Merge
       End If
   End With
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```